# Changing parsers in tika-config.xml results in "Unable to load org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser"

Tags: java, parsing, nutch, apache-tika

I'm trying to enable Tika's *BoilerpipeContentHandler* parser within Nutch to extract the article text from web pages. To do this, I've configured tika-config.xml to exclude the HTMLParser and activate the BoilerpipeContentHandler parser as follows:

```
<properties>
     <service-loader initializableProblemHandler="ignore" loadErrorHandler="WARN" />
 <parsers>
    <parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser">
      <mime-exclude>text/html</mime-exclude>
      <parser-exclude class="org.apache.tika.parser.html.HtmlParser"/>
    </parser>

 <!-- Use a different parser for text/html -->
    <parser class="org.apache.tika.parser.html.BoilerpipeContentHandler">
      <mime>text/html</mime>
    </parser>
  </parsers>
</properties>
```

When I test this configuration by running the command:

`bin/nutch org.apache.nutch.parse.ParserChecker`

The output includes:

```
Dec 12, 2019 5:11:40 PM org.apache.tika.config.LoadErrorHandler$2 handleLoadError
WARNING: Unable to load org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tika.parser.html.HtmlParser
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
```

and

```
Dec 12, 2019 5:11:40 PM org.apache.tika.config.LoadErrorHandler$2 handleLoadError
WARNING: Unable to load org.apache.tika.parser.html.BoilerpipeContentHandler
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tika.parser.html.BoilerpipeContentHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
```

I have the classpath set correctly, so I can't figure out why the two parser classes aren't being found. I'm wondering whether Nutch or Tika is using a different classpath perhaps? Or maybe there's something obviously wrong with my tika-config.xml.

I'd really appreciate any ideas you have.

Comment: "I have the classpath set correctly,..."  The stack traces say otherwise ;) SUGGESTION: focus on getting Tika to work - with *any* data file or *any* configuration: https://tika.apache.org/1.23/gettingstarted.html.  Then change one variable at a time, until you get it completely working in your environment,

Comment: ALSO: Q: Have you examined the .jar files to confirm that org.apache.tika.parser.html.BoilerpipeContentHandler exists?  If so, which .jar?  Q: What exactly *IS* your classpath, and how are you setting it?  Please update your post with answers to all of the above questions.

Comment: Thank you! Very good advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to focus on your end goal: *using the boilerplate extractor with Nutch*. Nutch already provides support for the boilerplate extractor from within Nutch itself, no need to change the `tika-config.xml`.

You need to set the `tika.extractor` property to `boilerpipe` in your `nutch-site.xml`. By default, Nutch will use the `ArticleExtractor` extractor.

You can check https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/conf/nutch-default.xml#L1645-L1677 for some additional configuration options that are exposed.

Comment: Ahh thank you! I didn't see that. Unfortunately, I've added those settings to nutch-site.xml and confirmed that Tika is still not running Boilerpipe on the content. I've confirmed this by comparing the output of the online Boilerpipe demo (https://boilerpipe-web.appspot.com/) to what nutch has crawled using bin/nutch readseg -dump crawl5/segments/20191213090608/t output -nofetch -noparse -noparsetext. Would you by any chance have a suggestion on where I could go from here to diagnose this? It'd be great if there was a way to enable verbose logging in Nutch to see what's happening.

Comment: Are you sure that you enabled the `parse-tika` plugin in the `plugin.includes` setting? Otherwise, it will use `parse-html` (i.e not Tika). Also since you're reading the segment it could be that you're reading the already crawled/parsed data (it will not be reprocessed). You can check the output of only the parser step with `bin/nutch parsechecker <URL>`.